# SQL delete query in cake php not affecting rows

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model-view-controller

I am new to cakephp and I am trying to use a delete query but no rows are affected and no errors are shown when running the following code:

```
$db=ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
  $query="DELETE FROM mst_medicines WHERE mst_medicines.id=".$id;

 if($db->rawQuery($query)){
    return true;
 }else{
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Is the query works when you run it directly on MySQL server.

Comment: yes but shows 0 rows affected, but no records are deleted @GauravLad

Comment: And kids, this is how an SQL injection vulnerability looks like... I hope that you have sanitized the `$id` value!

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is of type `UUID` (VARCHAR 36), you have to wrap it in quotes:

```
$query="DELETE FROM mst_medicines WHERE mst_medicines.id='{$id}'";
```

However, please note that this is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Unless there is a good reason to delete records this way, it is always better to use the `Model::delete()` method (I assume you are using CakePHP 2.x).